# Vue - Pushing array into nested array from callback

Tags: vue.js

I'm encoding images into base64 format in a component then trying to push the objects into an array.

Basically collection Item > Collection Item Images

```
<base64 :index="index" :multiple="true" :done="getFiles"></base64>

colItems: [
 {
   id: '1',
   title: 'Title 1',
   subTitle: 'Subtitle 1',
   colItemImgs: [],
  },
],

methods: {
    // Add images to ColItem
    getFiles(files) {
        console.log(files)
        this.colItems.colItemImgs.push(...files)
    },
}
```

I'm trying to specifically add them into the right object using the index. But haven't figured out how to pass the index back through the callback.

Thanks for your time

Base64 Component

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <v-btn raised @click="onPickItemFile(index)">base64</v-btn>
    <input type="file" @change="onChange" :multiple="multiple" 
     style="display: none" ref="foobar_y" />
   </div>
 </template>

<script>
 export default {
 props: {
  multiple: {
    default: false,
    type: Boolean,
  },
  done: {
    type: Function,
    default: () => {}
  },
  index: '',
},
methods: {
  onChange(e){
    // get the files
    let files = e.target.files;
    // Process each file
    var allFiles = []
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i]
      // Make new FileReader
      let reader = new FileReader()
      // Convert the file to base64 text
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
      // on reader load somthing...
      reader.onload = () => {
        // Make a fileInfo Object
        let fileInfo = {
          name: file.name,
          type: file.type,
          size: Math.round(file.size / 1000)+' kB',
          base64: reader.result,
          file: file
        }
        let index = this.index
        // Push it to the state
        allFiles.push(fileInfo)
        // If all files have been proceed
        if(allFiles.length == files.length){
          // Apply Callback function
          if(this.multiple) this.done(allFiles)
          else this.done(allFiles[0])
        }
      } // reader.onload
    } // for
  }, // onChange()
  onPickItemFile (index) {
    this.$refs.foobar_y.click()
  }, 
  }
 };
</script>
```

Comment: There is no colItemImgs on colItems. There is a colItemImgs on (potentially) elements of colItems. You should be pushing entire objects on colItems. Maybe something like this: this.colItems.push({id: '1', title: 'SomeTitle', subTitle: 'Some subtitle', colitemImgs: files})

Comment: Where are you using `getFiles()`—can you include that part of your code?

Comment: I've updated the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

colItems is an Array, like `a = [1,2,3,4]` if you want to access specific element inside array you need to provide index of that element like `a[0] // result-> 1`. so `colItemImgs` is not accessible by your method. find the index of the element you want to work with and use it by the method mentioned as above.

Comment: I seem to lose the index after passing into the base64 component. So the push would look something similar to this? this.colItems[index].colItemImgs.push(...files)